# How can I do an auto select in a ion search bar

Tags: ionic4

I'm setting up a search bar, but what I want to do is click on a icon then show the search bar, but when I try this code I need to click on the icon and then click again in the search bar. Is there way just by clicking on the icon show the search bar and start typing?

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="dark" class="center-textclass">
        <ion-searchbar autocomplete="on" debounce="500" mode ="ios" (ionChange)="buscar($event)" *ngIf="searchBar"  showCancelButton="always" (ionCancel)="searchBar=false; ionViewWillEnter()" animated> </ion-searchbar>  

        <ion-buttons slot="end" *ngIf="!searchBar">
            <ion-menu-button color="light" menu="primerMenu" mode="ios"></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>

        <ion-buttons slot="start" *ngIf="!searchBar">
            <ion-button (click)="searchBar=true"><ion-icon name="search" size="large" mode="ios"></ion-icon></ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ion-searchbar setFocus() method.
.html

```
<ion-buttons slot="end" *ngIf="!searchBar">
    <ion-menu-button color="light" menu="primerMenu" mode="ios"></ion-menu-button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-buttons slot="start" *ngIf="!searchBar">
    <ion-button (click)="(searchBar=true); focusSearchBar()">
        <ion-icon name="search" size="large" mode="ios"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>

<ion-searchbar #search [(ngModel)]="query"></ion-searchbar>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('search') search : any;

focusSearchBar(): void {
    this.search.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: already tried but  there is a error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFocus' of undefined"

Comment: Try using settimeout

Comment: same error :( , i have been trying a diferent forms but , is still the same error.